# Jquery Load not loading

Tags: jquery, load, loading

I'm trying to do a fairly simple load function with Jquery (at least I think it is), but it simply isn't loading anything.

On this page here (http://new.visibilitysoftware.com/careers/), I am trying to load the div#center-stage from here: http://www.vspublic.com/VSCareers/Careers.aspx. I have tried it with and without the /careers.aspx. I have also tried it with #center-stage and #center-stage.content as jquery parameters for the function.

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I simply can't find it. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code here with your question. Thanks.

Comment: Same origin policy means you can only use ajax to load documents from the same domain/origin. You're trying to load content from a different domain

Comment: Issue with jquery Easing..use firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not be able to load data from external site because `The Same Origin Policy` enforced by the browsers.

Workaround for this is to implement `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` header in the response from `http://www.vspublic.com/VSCareers/Careers.aspx`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Took a quick look at the page. This is happening due to restrictions due to same origin policy.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.vspublic.com/VSCareers/Careers.aspx. Origin http://new.visibilitysoftware.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

One way to use it is JSONP. I know an example would be helpful. Will add it as soon as I get some time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I appreciate it!